# Determine if the contract transaction came from another contract or wallet account

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Let's say, I've a function defined on contract and anyone can call that function(a user, a different contract etc.).

Is there a way to identify within that function if it is a contract address or a user address in solidity? And if it is a contract, is it possible to identify the type of the contract?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If `tx.origin == msg.sender`, then you know the call is coming from a "user address". If not, then it is coming from a contract.

Note that this is not guaranteed to be true forever, and it probably isn't a good idea to even make a distinction between "user" and contract accounts in your code; the long term plan for Ethereum is to eliminate this distinction entirely, and have all accounts be contracts (which may behave just like user acounts).